# How to inject delay between the window and sink operator?

Tags: java, apache-flink, stream-processing, amazon-kinesis-analytics

### Context - Application

We have an Apache Flink application which processes events

- The application uses event time characteristics
- The application shards (`keyBy`) events based on the `sessionId` field
- The application has windowing with 1 minute tumbling window

  - The windowing is specified by a `reduce` and a `process` functions
  - So, for each session we will have 1 computed record
- The application emits the data into a Postgres sink

### Context - Infrastructure

Application:

- It is hosted in AWS via Kinesis Data Analytics (KDA)
- It is running in 5 different regions
- The exact same code is running in each region

Database:

- It is hosted in AWS via RDS (currently it is a PostgreSQL)
- It is located in one region (with a read replica in a different region)

#### Problem

Because we are using event time characteristics with 1 minute tumbling window all regions' sink emit their records nearly at the same time.

[image: Current State]

What we want to achieve is to add artificial delay between window and sink operators to postpone sink emition.

[image: Desired State]

| Flink App | Offset | Window 1 | Sink 1st run | Window 2 | Sink 2nd run |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #1 | 0 | 60 | 60 | 120 | 120 |
| #2 | 12 | 60 | 72 | 120 | 132 |
| #3 | 24 | 60 | 84 | 120 | 144 |
| #4 | 36 | 60 | 96 | 120 | 156 |
| #5 | 48 | 60 | 108 | 120 | 168 |

#### Not working work-around

We have thought that we can add some sleep to [evictor's `evictBefore`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#evictors) like this

```java
...
.keyBy(event -> event.getSessionId())
.window(getWindowAssigner(config))
.allowedLateness(Time.seconds(config.getWindowLatenessInSec()))
.evictor(new Evictor<>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5373966807521260856L;

    public void evictBefore(Iterable<TimestampedValue<Event>> iterable, int i, TimeWindow timeWindow, EvictorContext evictorContext) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(config.getWindowingDelayInMilliSec());
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void evictAfter(Iterable<TimestampedValue<Event>> iterable, int i, TimeWindow timeWindow, EvictorContext evictorContext) {

    }
})
...
```

but it does not work reliably.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `TumblingEventTimeWindows of(Time size, Time offset, WindowStagger windowStagger)` with `WindowStagger.RANDOM`.

See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/assigners/WindowStagger.html for documentation.

Comment: Hi David, how does it help to set a specific offset?

Comment: Maybe `TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(config.getWindowSizeInSec()), Time.seconds(config.getWindowDelayInSec()))` would be also fine for us... Let me test it and I'll update you.

Comment: It seems like it is also fine for us if we shift the windows. So we don't have put artificial delays between window and sink operators.